# VBA How to get path to The Current Users Application data folder?

Tags: vba, windows, ms-word, filesystems

In general,

Using VBA, how do I determine where the Current users Application Data folder is?

The FileSystemObjects special folders only knows about 3 folders

- WindowsFolder
- SystemFolder
- TemporaryFolder

Specifically, I need a Word Macro to copy a file to the a folder under the Application Data folder.

e.g. In VB.Net I can use `My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.CurrentUserApplicationData` to do this

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You can use `Environ("AppData")` to get this path.  Environ will pull any system variable, which can be found by using the `set` command at the DOS prompt.

Comment: I never thought to check the Environment strings, this works a treat, thanks :)

Comment: I think the Environ() approach is unreliable as environmental variables can be changed by the user and can lead to unexpected results. Using the Windows API might be better. Here's an example for finding the Documents / My Documents folder: http://dailydoseofexcel.com/archives/2009/02/26/get-the-path-to-my-documents-in-vba/#comment-38211 If you can find a way to do it for the AppData folder it could be a better way.

Answer (score 17):

Using `advapi32.dll`, you can get the `USERPROFILE` via

```
Environ("USERPROFILE")
```

Connect this with the "Application Data" directory (which has a standard, specific name) to get what you want

```
CStr(Environ("USERPROFILE") & "\Application Data")
```

For more information, check out [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0fx287h4.aspx)

Comment: Alternative to converting to a string with `CStr()` is to just explicitly ask for the string data type using its type character `$` before runtime - `Environ$()`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how, in VBA, to generate a list of `envstring` names and their corresponding `number` for use with the [`Environ(envstring,number)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/environ-function) function, which I adapted from [this Excel VBA sample](https://www.tek-tips.com/faqs.cfm?fid=4296).

```
Sub List_Environment_Variables()

    Dim EnvString As String
    Indx = 1

    Do
        EnvString = Environ(Indx)
        If EnvString = "" Then
            Exit Do
        Else
            Debug.Print Indx & "> " & EnvString
            Indx = Indx + 1
        End If
    
    Loop Until EnvString = ""

    Debug.Print "- - - - - - - - - - - - - -"

End Sub
```

Comment: This is the only answer that uses *working* VBA code as requested.

Answer (score 0):

Use this for just returning the name of the specific user that is logged in.

```
MsgBox Left(Replace(Environ("APPDATA"), Left(Environ("APPDATA"), InStr(1, Environ("APPDATA"), "Users") + 5), ""), InStr(1, Replace(Environ("APPDATA"), Left(Environ("APPDATA"), InStr(1, Environ("APPDATA"), "Users") + 5), ""), "\") - 1), vbOKOnly
```

Comment: environ("Username") is doing just fine for that.